# Weapon results in "The Transporter"

Tags: realism, the-transporter

I was watching "The Transporter", and I was wondering about the results of the weapon impacts during the attack on Frank's house. It looks as if the bullets go right through the walls, as if the walls are made out of paper. Is that true (i.e. that houses in that region are build out of paper-thin walls), or are the weapons they are using, for example a Steyr AUG, that powerfull? Or is it simply a plot device?

Comment: *[Are] houses in that region are build out of paper-thin walls[?]* → The houses in that region (south of France, "Côte d'Azur") are traditionally made of stones, sometimes bricks. The walls are rather thick. I do not recall the material of Frank's house but it was definitely a traditional house so it will be most likely stone.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm no expert, but a real assault rifle's bullet is usually not stopped by e.g. a door, a tree or a simple brick wall. Most of the "cover" you see in the movies would not do in real life (e.g. cars) - apart from hiding you from the sight of your enemy of course.

So depending on the material Frank's house is made of, I would imagine that you cannot trust in the walls shielding you from the bullets. However, if the bullets would really penetrate the walls by the dozen, as you see it in the movie, I do not know...